# Proving 3 statements with "if and only if".

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Lets say I've got three statements A, B and C. I want to prove:

$A \Leftrightarrow B \Leftrightarrow C$

Is it enough to only prove the following?

$ A \Rightarrow B \Rightarrow C \Rightarrow A$

If yes, why?

Comment: Yes, it is, because implication is transitive.

Comment: As @BrianM.Scott said that's because of transitivity. But, if you are suspicious, you can form the logic table and investigate its truth and falseness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, because if you have

$$A\implies B\implies C$$

you have already got "one direction".

But also $C\implies A$, so

$$A\iff C.$$

And $B\implies C$ and $C\iff A$, so $B\implies A$.

So

$$A\iff B.$$

Finally,

$$A\iff B\iff C.$$